# Error: Call to undefined function Craft\mb_convertOcase() after updating to 2.6.3017

Tags: updating, updates

Just updated Craft 2.6.3002 to 2.6.3017 and am getting the following error in the CP & front-end: `Call to undefined function Craft\mb_convertOcase()` `/craft/app/helpers/StringHelper.php(558)`. On line 558 of this file, I have `return mb_convert_case($string, MB_CASE_UPPER, static::UTF8);`. Where is `O` coming from?

Screenshot of error & stack trace: [image: Screenshot of error & stack trace]

Comment: It is correct in their git. Copy the line https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop-v2/src/helpers/StringHelper.php#L558 or download the entire Craft folder and you should be fine. Bug reports don't belong here, please contact pixel and tonic directly if there are other issues

Comment: As I mentioned above, line 558 in my StringHelper.php file is correct. Also, how am I supposed to necessarily know ahead of time is something is indeed a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I performed a manual upgrade as documented at https://docs.craftcms.com/v2/updating.html#manually-updating and the error automagically disappeared. Therefore, it looks like there was a glitch in the One-click Updating in this particular case.

Comment: That's super weird...